# How do you get the width of a shape that's already created in d3?

Tags: d3.js

```
cells.append('rect')
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.dy; })
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.children ? null : color(d.parent.name); })

cells.append('text')
      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x + d.dx / 2 })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y + d.dy / 2 })
      .attr('fill', 'white')
      .attr('font-size', 14)
      .text(function (d) {
         if (d.name.length < cells.rect.width) {
              return d.name;
         }
       });
```

I don't know why

`cells.rect.width`

doesn't work? But what I want to know is how I get check the width of the shape before appending the text on to the shape.

I also tried pushing the width of the shapes to an array, and then use indexing loop to loop through the array to check to see if the length of the name is longer than the width of the box. The problem with that is when the shapes are created, the shape(box) with the biggest area are created first. On the other hand, when text are appended, it starts from bottom right to top left.

I understand that the length of the text and pixels are two different units, but I am going to put in a simple ratio convert it. How do I get the width of the rect that is already drawn on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the element (`this`) and its `bbox` to get the actual width. This will not work as you want it to though, because you are comparing the *number of characters* with the *width in pixels*. To make it work, you need to draw the text first, then check its width compared to the `rect` and remove it if it is too large.

The code for this (after having drawn `rect`s and text) would be something like this.

```
cells.selectAll("text")
     .text(function(d, i) {
       if(this.getBBox().width <
               document.querySelectorAll("svg > rect")[i].getBBox.width) {
         return d.name;
       }
     });
```

Comment: Ahh, this solution doesn't work. But i should have stated the question in a more clear fashion. I understand that the length of the text and pixels are two different units, but I am going to put in a simple ratio convert it.

Comment: If I already have .rect on the screen, how do i grab the width? Thanks in advance

Comment: You would use something like the second term in the `if` statement. The exact selector ("svg > rect") depends on the structure of your SVG.

Answer (score 3):

The rect object has an attributes child inside it.

```
cells.rect.attributes.width.value
```

might work instead.